# java.lang.IllegalStateException: ImageLoader must be init with configuration before using

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

My app uses Universal ImageLoader and is on production now.
I installed bugsense(MINT) and reported this error.
I have already initialised ImageLoader in application class but somehow application instance is dead and activity is still trying to use this library onResume.
any help would be appreciated.

Here is initalize code in application class.

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisk(true)
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
        .build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .writeDebugLogs()
    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
    .diskCacheExtraOptions(480, 320, null)
    .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Comment: please update coding

Comment: as you can see, initialise code is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Can you please try init using `ImageLoaderConfiguration`

```
protected ImageLoader imageLoader;

imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));
```

Comment: actually this issue is not related with ImageLoader initialisation. my code works well when I test but I suspect that activity tries to use ImageLoader instance when application instance is dead somehow from the crash report

Comment: How does it crash? Is the activity was on the background or something?

Comment: I am not sure how it did crash. but it's true that app crashed and application instance was dead. but activity was alive and tried to use ImageLoader instance. that's all what I can guess.

Comment: yes. This is correct. I have included this in constructor